# The lspci -vvv output CorrErr and UnCorrErr changes over time

Tags: command-line

The `lspci -vvv` output shows flags such as `CorrErr` and `UnCorrErr`.
I'm wondering if these flags can indicate health of the device and if they change over time.

A sample output is reported below.

```
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast TAbort- TAbort- MAbort- SERR- PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at f6101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Region 1: Memory at f6100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 3
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME+
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
            DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s 64ns, L1 1us
                    ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
            DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                    RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                    MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 16384 bytes
            DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
            LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited
                    ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
            LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
                    ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [94] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
            Address: fffffffc  Data: 0000
```

Answer (score 1):

The link from another post of this thread "cirrascale.com/blog/index.php/pci-debugging-101/" does not work anymore in 2019. However I have found the article archived in:

https://intrepid.warped.com/~scotte/OldBlogEntries/web/index-5.html

Here is an extract from the linked article:

> specifying the particular device (this time “ 0000 : 02 : 00 . 0 “) will get us details.
>
> `# lspci -s 0000:02:00.0 -vvv`
>
> Giving the output:
>
> `02:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)`
>
> ...
>
> `DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-`
>
> ...
>
> `CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+`
>
> `CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+`
>
> We can see from the device status registers (“ DevSta “) that the device has experienced some sort of correctable error (“ CorrErr+ “).
>
> Since the error was a correctable error (“ CorrErr “), the interesting part of the AER output is the correctable error status (“ CESta “).  None of the bits are set except for the non-fatal error bit (“ NoNFatalErr+ “).  By the name of it (it’s an error, but not a fatal one… and it was correctable!), this sounds like nothing to really be concerned about.  Checking if the error is masked or not (“ CEMsk “) shows that the device vendor elected to mask that error (“ NonFatalErr+ “), so they didn’t think it was something that should be tricked up the PCIe device chain and handled either.  In truth, the PCI-SIG defines Correctable Non Fatal Errors as “Advisory” errors, and note that is should be used as an indication of a software problem, not to be indicative of an issue with the integrity or functionality of the PCIe bus.
>
> As is probably obvious, there’s not usually much call for looking at PCIe devices that are embedded on a commodity motherboard, but the steps to figuring out where a particular device lives on a PCIe bus, and how it is behaving are the same for most any device.  A more common case these days, as I mentioned earlier, is helping customers and partners follow these same steps for products like our GB5400.

Answer (score 0):

No, tracking down masked correctable errors usually only makes sense if it is materially impacting performance of the PCIe devices.

http://www.cirrascale.com/blog/index.php/pci-debugging-101/

Comment: Thanks Frank. The link you posted is exactly what I'm looking for.